# How to implement dynamic bitset in my specific code

Tags: c++, bitset

I am using bitset and to improve the performance of my code I want to change it to dynamic bitset, but after reading some posts related to this, I still don't know the way to define my code.

So I attached my code and I would like to know if any of you could help me giving me some ideas about what should I modify and how.

Thanks in advance :)

```
// Program that converts a number from decimal to binary and show the positions
// where the bit of the number in binary contains 1

#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    unsigned long long int dec;
    bitset<5000> binaryNumber;
    bitset<5000> mask;
    mask = 0x1;

    cout << "Write a number in decimal: ";
    cin >> dec;

    // Conversion from decimal to binary
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < binaryNumber.size(); x++)
    {
        binaryNumber[x] = dec % 2;
        dec = dec / 2;
    }

    cout << "The number " << dec << " in binary is: ";
    for (x = (binaryNumber.size() - 1); x >= 0; x--)
    {
        cout << binaryNumber[x];
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Storage of the position with 1 values
    vector<int> valueTrue;
    for (int r = 0; r < binaryNumber.size(); r++) //
    {
        if (binaryNumber.test(r) & mask.test(r)) // if both of them are bit "1"
                                                 // we store in valueTrue vector
        {
            valueTrue.push_back(r);
        }
        mask = mask << 1;
    }


    int z;
    cout << "Bit 1 are in position: ";
    for (z = 0; z < valueTrue.size(); z++)
    {
        cout << valueTrue.at(z) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the variable `dec` you use is 64 bit, so this won't work correctly for larger numbers and the 5000 bits bitset is useless this way. You should store the number in a string instead.

Comment: @schnaader. Thanks schnaader. I was thinking about the highest performance variable to the variable dec but I think the only solution will be store dec as a string, as you recommend. So thanks for your entry. :)

Comment: `std::vector<std::bitset<1>> bitset_var;` I have this workaround from this problem. Not sure if this would help you. Just put it out there. Might help some in far future. :)

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to have a dynamic bitset is to use one ;)
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html

UPDATE : providing a full example

```
#include<iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
int main() {
    unsigned long long dec;
    std::cout << "Write a number in decimal: ";
    std::cin >> dec;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bs(64, dec);
    std::cout << bs << std::endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 64; i++){
        if(bs[i])
            std::cout << "Position " << i << " is 1" << std::endl;
    }
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeap! This is what I have been looking at, even the same link, but even with the examples I don't see the way to do it in my code... Could you help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: here you go. I hope I undestood what you wanted. I used 64 as max length, as anyway you're just reading an int

Comment: `dynamic_bitset` constructor expects `unsigned long`, not `unsigned long long`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#cons2

Answer (score 6):

For those who don't use Boost - you can use `vector<bool>` which is optimized so each element uses only 1 bit.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/

Answer (score 4):

Here's your program roughly re-written with `dynamic_bitset`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Write a number in decimal: ";
    unsigned long long dec;
    std::cin >> dec;

    // Conversion from decimal to binary
    std::string str;
    for(unsigned long long d = dec; d>0; d/=2)
        str.insert(str.begin(), boost::lexical_cast<char>(d&1) );
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> binaryNumber(str);
    std::cout << "The number " << dec << " in binary is: " << binaryNumber<<'\n';

   // Storage of the position with 1 values
   std::vector<size_t> valueTrue;
   for( size_t pos = binaryNumber.find_first();
        pos != boost::dynamic_bitset<>::npos;
        pos = binaryNumber.find_next(pos))
       valueTrue.push_back(pos);

   std::cout<<"Bit 1 are in position: ";
   for(size_t z=0; z < valueTrue.size(); ++z)
       std::cout << valueTrue[z] << " ";
   std::cout << "\n";
}
```

test run: https://ideone.com/OdhWE

Note, you cannot immediately construct the bitset from your integer because its constructor [expects `unsigned long`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#cons2). If you can get by with unsigned longs, the whole conversion loop is unnecessary

Comment: Wowwwww!! Your programming skills are simply amazing! I've never imagined writing something like this. I hope in the future I am able to do the same. Now I have two doubts. 1.Which are the benefits of using using namespace std; at the beginning of the code or writing std:: when necesary?? 2. I need to link the libraries  <boost/lexical_cast.hpp> and <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp> to run my program. I have found them here: www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/boost/lexical_cast.hpp and www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp, but how do I link them to my code??

Comment: @thomas 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c  2. You said you were looking into `dynamic_bitset`. Boost is the library that provides it, along with many other useful things. See http://www.boost.org for details.

Comment: One question about the variable dec, declared as unsigned long long. As I want to use it for larger numbers as for example for 5000 bits bitset, I was thinking about declare this variable as string. But I couldn´t make mathematical operations to convert it into binary. What would you recommend me to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)'s [dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).

Comment: Yeap! This is what I have been looking at, but even with the examples I don't see the way to do it in my code... Could you help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @thomas: The documentation is quite detailed. Have you a specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using std::bitset is to define a large enough bitset, for example bitset<1000>.

Then you can use a variable to control the actual bits and you still can use the member functions of bitset

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without using the boost library.

You can dynamically assign the bitset. So instead of

```
for(x=0;x<binaryNumber.size();x++)
{
    binaryNumber[x]=dec%2;
    dec=dec/2;
}
```

You can simply do:

```
 binaryNumber = dec;
```

Yes it does work!!

Then rather than using a separate vector to store the positions of the 1s, you can do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<binaryNumber.size();i++){
    if(binaryNumber[i])
        cout << "Position of 1: " << i << endl;
}
```

Hope it helps.